# Manipulating the output string in bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have written a line that finds and returns the full path to a desired file. The output is as follows:

```
/home/ke/Desktop/b/o/r/files.txt:am.torrent
/home/ke/Desktop/y/u/n/u/s/files.txt:asd.torrent
```

I have to modify the output like this:

```
bor
yunus
```

How do I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
your_script.sh | sed 's,.*Desktop,,' | sed 's,[^/]*$,,' | sed s,/,,g
```

or, even better:

```
your_script.sh | sed 's,.*Desktop,,;s,[^/]*$,,;s,/,,g'
```

Comment: Three instances of sed? Don't you think that's overkill?

Comment: No, I don't think it's an overkill, it will work fast. But yes, it can be done in one invocation of sed as well.

Comment: You can run multiple sed commands in a single instance by separating the commands with `;`, like this: `sed -e 's,.*Desktop,,; s,[^/]*$,,; s,/,,g'`

Answer (score 0):

With sed. `echo '/home/ke/Desktop/b/o/r/files.txt:am.torrent' | sed -e 's+/++g' -e 's/^.*Desktop//' -e 's/files.txt:.*$//'`. This is a fairly trivial solution, and I'm sure there are better ones.

Answer (score 0):

Id resort to awk:

```
BEGIN { FS="/" }

{
  for(i=1;i<NF;i++)
    if (length($i) == 1)
      a[NR]=a[NR]""$i
}
END {
  for (i in a)
    print a[i]
}
```

use it like this:

```
$ awk -f script.awk input
bor
yunus
```

or if you have your data in a variable:

```
$ awk -f script.awk <<< $data
```

Comment: But what if the input line is `/home/q/Desktop/b/o/r/files.txt:am.torrent`?

Comment: well, yes that is a problem since you'd get `qbor` but that format wasn't given in OPs tetstdata. I'll wait with a complete general solution until OP request such...

Comment: But the possibility was implied. `/home/ke/Desktop` suggests that he's scanning user homedirs. It isn't usual, but there's nothing forbidding a single-character username.

Comment: if it's the users home-dir thats an issue then simply change the for-loop to `for(i=4;i<NF;i++)` instead. Until OP states differently I'll stick to KISS.

Answer (score 0):

it's not a nice/tidy solution, but bash parameter expansion is a powerful tool. So could not resist providing an example

```
[]l="/home/ke/Desktop/b/o/r/files.txt:am.torrent"
[]m=${l##*Desktop/}
[]n=${m%%/files.txt*}
[]k=${n//\//}
[]echo $m
b/o/r/files.txt:am.torrent
[]echo $n
b/o/r
[]echo $k
bor
```

You can see how nicely bash is replacing the variable step by step without using any external program (btw `[]` is PS1, prompt)
There can be many more ways to do it. I got another one while writing the first

```
[]l="/home/ke/Desktop/b/o/r/files.txt:am.torrent"
[]m=${l/*Desktop\//}
[]n=${m/\/files.txt*/}
[]k=${n//\//}
[]echo $m
b/o/r/files.txt:am.torrent
[]echo $n
b/o/r
[]echo $k
bor
```

Try some more,

Comment: Sorry lost track of the original question, you can read line by line in a while to use this